# How to handle user interactions in subviews with iOS MVVM

Tags: ios, mvvm, viewmodel, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

For implementing MVVM with a table view controller, it is often to have a single parent view model and a bunch of child view models for each cell. Let's say each cell has a like button, and now the user taps one of the like buttons.

After searching through stack overflow, I see three possible ways to handle the flow:

1. The tapped action is sent to the child view model, the child view model handles the like action internally.
2. The tapped action is sent to the child view model, the child view models pass the intent to the parent view model, which handles the like action.
3. The tapped action is sent to the table view controller (using cell delegate or closure), the table view controller then pass the tapped action to the parent view model.

Personally, I prefer the 2nd and 3rd approach. What confuses me is that in the 3rd approach, the child view model is only responsible for the output (presenting data), but not for the input (handling interactions). Instead,  the parent view model is responsible for handling the child view's interaction. Because normally a view model will handle both for its view.

Which approach is better? Or are there better ways to achieve the same goal?
Any advise would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question I would ask myself in this situation is whether any state in the view controller has to change based on inputs into the cell. If so, then option 2 is the best choice (assuming RxSwift.) If you are using delegates/closures instead of Observables then option 3 is handy to reduce the number of delegates required.

From your description, it doesn't sound like the view controller's state needs to be updated when the user taps the button, so option 1 sounds like the best.

Here is how I would likely implement it using my [CLE architecture](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools)... You can think of the `connect` functions as view models.

```
extension ViewController {
    // The view controller doesn't have much to do. Just fetch the array of
    // likables and show them on the table view.
    func connect(api: API) {
        api.response(.fetchLikables)
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: LikableCell.self)) { _, item, cell in
                cell.connect(api: api, item: item)
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        api.error
            .map { $0.localizedDescription }
            .bind(onNext: presentScene(animated: true) { message in
                UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert).scene {
                    $0.connectOK()
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

extension LikableCell {
    // The cell has the interesting behavior. If the thing is liked, then the
    // `likeButton` is selected. When the button is tapped, update the state
    // and send the network request. If the request fails, then reset the state.
    func connect(api: API, item: LikableThing) {
        enum Input {
            case tap
            case updateSucceeded
            case updateFailed
        }
        cycle(
            input: likeButton.rx.tap.map(to: Input.tap),
            initialState: (current: item.isLiked, reset: item.isLiked),
            reduce: { state, input in
                switch input {
                case .tap:
                    state.current.toggle() // toggle the like state right away.
                case .updateSucceeded:
                    state.reset = state.current // if server success, update the reset
                case .updateFailed:
                    state.current = state.reset // if server fail, update the current state.
                }
            },
            reaction: { args in
                args
                    .filter { $0.1 == .tap } // only make network request when user taps
                    .flatMapLatest { state, _ in
                        return api.successResponse(.setLikable(id: item.id, isLiked: !state.current))
                            .map { $0 ? Input.updateSucceeded : Input.updateFailed }
                    }
            }
        )
        .map { $0.current }
        .bind(to: likeButton.rx.isSelected)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

struct LikableThing: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Identifier<Int, LikableThing>
    let isLiked: Bool
}

extension Endpoint where Response == [LikableThing] {
    static let fetchLikables: Endpoint = Endpoint(
        request: apply(URLRequest(url: baseURL)) { request in
            // configure request
        },
        decoder: JSONDecoder()
    )
}

extension Endpoint where Response == Void {
    static func setLikable(id: LikableThing.ID, isLiked: Bool) -> Endpoint {
        let request = URLRequest(url: baseURL)
        // configure request
        return Endpoint(request: request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. But how do I keep data in sync between parent and child view models ? The child view model updates the post internally, but the old post still lives in the parent view model (inside an array of posts). If I then update the post array it will trigger the parent to produce new child view models, which seems like there is no point updating in the child view model.

Comment: The old post doesn't live in the parent view model inside an array of posts, because there is no array of posts inside the parent view model. If you set up something that would cause `fetchPosts` to be called again, the server will send you properly synced data.

Comment: I see. What confuses me is that when the server sends the updated posts back to the parent view model, it triggers the parent view model to create a new set of child view models, which then triggers the table view to update the data, which causes the cell to be updated, but the cell itself is already updated by the cell view model already. This duplicate update seems unnecessary.

Comment: Also does "no array of posts" imply that the view model need to communicate with the model via some sort of post identifier ? (for example the if a user wants to delete a specific post)  Thanks.

Comment: The server doesn't send the updated posts back to the parent view model. The `fetchPosts` call is only made when the view first loads (called in the `viewDidLoad`). You would have to add code to the above to cause `fetchPosts` to be called again (maybe a pull to refresh?) If you wanted to add a `deletePost` feature, *that* would be put in the parent view model.

Comment: If deleting is a feature, then the tableView *is* affected by user action, and option (2) is the better choice.